# How to convert numeric values to missing in a Julia DataFrame column?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Trying to replace values of 99 to missing:

```
df_miss = DataFrame(a=[1,2,99,99,5,6,99])
allowmissing!(df_miss)
df_miss.a .= replace.(df_miss.a, 99 => missing)
```

But getting this error:

```
MethodError: no method matching similar(::Int64, ::Type{Union{Missing, Int64}})
```

Using: 
Julia Version 1.5.3 
DataFrames Version 0.22.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use broadcasting here. Just write:

```
julia> df_miss = DataFrame(a=[1,2,99,99,5,6,99])
7×1 DataFrame
 Row │ a
     │ Int64
─────┼───────
   1 │     1
   2 │     2
   3 │    99
   4 │    99
   5 │     5
   6 │     6
   7 │    99

julia> df_miss.a = replace(df_miss.a, 99 => missing)
7-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 1
 2
  missing
  missing
 5
 6
  missing

julia> df_miss
7×1 DataFrame
 Row │ a
     │ Int64?
─────┼─────────
   1 │       1
   2 │       2
   3 │ missing
   4 │ missing
   5 │       5
   6 │       6
   7 │ missing
```

Comment: I see. So use broadcasting when replacing whole cell AND part of the cell value, for example: `df_2 = DataFrame(a_str=["a","b","c","x","e","1 x","x 2","3 x 4"])` `replace.(df_2.a_str, "x" => "y")` vs. `replace(df_2.a_str, "x" => "y")` will only replace instances of "x" and not "1 x".

Comment: `replace` already works on whole vectors so you should not broadcast it. Use broadcasting for methods that work on scalars.